# SIF parameter that determines Solr core prefix

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I am having some trouble with correctly configuring the Solr core prefix using SIF.

How is the to use Solr core prefix determined in the SIF installation for Sitecore 9?

For example, will;

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Sitename MySite ...
```

result in a `MySite_` Solr core prefix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SIF is offer you flexibility to choose Core prefix name.

You can have something like:

```
$prefix = "myprefix"
$PSScriptRoot = Resolve-Path -Path ".\XP0 Configuration files 9.0.1 rev. 171219"


$SolrUrl = "https://solr:8983/solr"
$SolrRoot = "C:\solr\solr-6.6.2"
$SolrService = "solr-6.6.2"


$solrParams = @{
   Path        = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"
   SiteName    = "www.mysite.local"
   SolrUrl     = $SolrUrl
   SolrRoot    = $SolrRoot
   SolrService = $SolrService
   CorePrefix  = $prefix
}
```

And to install just use next task with **solrParams** parameter

```
   Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams
```

Comment: Thanks for the trigger, in my case I overlooked the `SolrCorePrefix` parameter in `sitecore-XP0.json`. This parameter is used to construct `Solr.Core.Name` and this is used to configure core name in Sitecore.